# Window on top of other window

Tags: cocoa

I have two  `NSWindows` ( independent windows,No Parent and Child relationship), One Window should always be on top of the other Window.When I minimize and again maximize the mainWindow,second window should be on top of it. I used the `makeKeyAndOrderFront` to keep the window on top of the mainWindow  `[[self window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];` How can I achieve the above functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar question posted earlier: 
[NSWindow - show new window that will always stay on top of current window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723578/nswindow-show-new-window-that-will-always-stay-on-top-of-current-window)

Hope this helps :)